# Email signature fallback font is not working

Tags: email, fonts, signature, newsletter, fallback

I have a custom typekit font used in an email signature with Georgia used as the fallback font.

On a mobile device, it will not fallback on Georgia. However, Georgia will load if I remove the custom font.

Am I missing anything?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Signature</title>
<style type="text/css">
 @import url("https://use.typekit.net/rzf8bdg.css");
 body {
  font-family: 'Bressay', Georgia, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: left;
 }
 td {}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <div>
     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 320px;">
   <tr>
    <td width="31.25%"><a href="https://fertilityconsultants.ca"><img src="https://fertilityconsultants.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/cfc-logo-es.jpg" alt="CFC logo"/></a></td>
    <td valign="center" style="padding-left: 10px;">
     <strong style="font-size: 16px;">First Last Name</strong><br/>
     <em style="font-size:12px; margin-bottom:6px;">Job position</em><br/>
     <strong style="font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #66905f;">T</strong> (555) 555.5555&nbsp;<strong style="font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #66905f;">EXT</strong> 555<br/>
     <strong style="font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #66905f;">C</strong> (555) 555.5555<br/>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bressay is not a web safe font. You're missing the code you would need to link it to Adobe to work as a web font. Please post your html code, including the header, so people can offer a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @gwally Edited the original snippet to include the html code and header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bressay is never going to work in Outlook or Gmail, since they don't work with web fonts like Google Fonts. I used your code and could not really tell if it was working for me or if it was Georgia, a web safe font that looks darn close. Here are some suggestions to make sure you always display a serif font for First Last Name.

In the `head` change your body declaration to remove the sans-serif backup:

```
body, table.body, td {
    font-family: Bressay, Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

- Adobe does not use single quotes around the font name, try it without.
- In addition to the `body` tag above, I also added `table.body` and `td` to the css. This will work with the parts where you wanted a sans-serif font instead.

I added the font-family tag directly to the `strong` tag in the signature.:

```
<strong style="font-family: bressay, Georgia, serif; font-size: 16px;">First Last Name</strong>
```

After doing this, I got a serif font in Gmail and Android.

I tested this in Litmus and it works fine for all desktop and mobile clients.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I removed Bressay because it's useless if it doesn't work in Outlook or Gmail. I added your code and I'm happy with the results.